# Rails multiple polymorphic associations in memberships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two table "users" and "structures". I'd like to create a relation between them in this way :

A structure could have many users as members
A structure could have many structures as members

So a user can be members of many structures
a structure can be members of many structures

I create a table named "Memberships" with two polymophics associations :

```
create_table :memberships do |t|
  t.references :is_memberable, index: true, polymorphic: true
  t.references :has_memberable, index: true, polymorphic: true

  t.string :kind

  t.timestamps
end
```

But what should I do in my model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution :

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :is_memberships, :as => :is_memberable, :class_name => 'Membership'
  has_many :is_members_structures, through: :is_memberships, source: :is_memberable, source_type: 'Structure'
end
```

Membership.rb

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :is_memberable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :has_memberable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Structure.rb

```
class Structure < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :is_memberships, :as => :is_memberable, :class_name => 'Membership'
  has_many :has_memberships, :as => :has_memberable, :class_name => 'Membership'
end
```